# how to give UserCredentials in Google Calendar v3 Apis as like in Google.GData.Calendar api in c#.net

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api

I am currently using the Google.GData.Calendar api to exchange the events with my calendar system, in c#.net program.  In the GData api I can select, insert, update and delete the events using the user credentials on the `Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService` as below code

```
service = new CalendarService("myApp");
service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);
```

and I want to know that is there a way to set the user credentials in Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 same as above, and is it necessary to authenticate the `CalendarService` with either OAuth1.0 or OAuth2.0 in the Google.Apis.Calendar.v3?

And One more thing I was wondering if google may remove `Google.GData.CalendarService` Api completely in the future?